# Hi, i want to limit flexi slider images in loop, by fetching from database, my project is in codeignitor

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="content-bottom-in">
                <ul id="flexiselDemo1">


                <?php $tg = $this->db->get_where("mobile_accessories",array("acs_category"=>"Tempered_glass","product_status"=>1))->result();
                foreach($tg as $g){
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="w3l-specilamk">
                            <div class="speioffer-agile">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="<?php echo ($g->accessories_image!='')?base_url().$g->accessories_image:base_url()."img/doc/no_image.jpg";?>" width="160px;" height="160px;" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-name-w3l">
                                <h4 style="text-align:center">
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('Dashboard/single_mobile_acs'); ?>"><?php echo $g->accessories_name ?></a>
                                </h4>
                                <div class="w3l-pricehkj" style="padding-left:50px">
                                    <span class="item_price"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $g->accessories_discount_price ?></span><br>
                                        <del><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $g->accessories_actual_price ?></del>

                                </div>
                                <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details item_add single-item hvr-outline-out">
                                        <form action="#" method="post">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <a href="#"  onclick="add_product('<?php echo $g->accessories_id ?>')"><input  name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button"/></a>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome. "_i want to limit flexi slider images in loop, by fetching from database_" Ok, go for it, or are you having problems somewhere? What is your question?

Comment: Don't place `<input>` inside `<a></a>`